# How to get the number(count) of open MDI children

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, mdichild

I want to get the number of MDI children that opened.

**For example in c#**

```
this.MdiChildren.Count()
```

**Another example by an image:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`QMdiArea::subWindowList()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#subWindowList) method returns a [`QList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html) of MDI child windows.  `QList` has a [`count()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#count-2) method.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please give me a simple example.

Comment: Seriously? I though the documentation I pointed you to was pretty straight forward: `QMdiArea mdi; mdi.addSubWindow(...); ... int count = mdi.subWindowList().count();`